# Applescript to open Terminal window without sourcing ~/.bash_profile

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to use [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to create an app launcher for an interactive command-line program on OSX 10.8.  I want to be able to double-click on my application, and have a Terminal window open, running my program.  The problem is that my Applescript, (borrowed from Octave, and adapted for [Julia](http://julialang.org)) launches a Terminal window and attempts to spit some commands into it, however I have a rather hefty `~/.bash_profile` that interferes with this.  Is there a way to get my Applescript to open a non-login shell, or not source `~/.bash_profile`, etc?

Here's the script that Platypus runs:

```
# This is the startup procedure written as AppleScript to open a
# Terminal.app (if the Terminal.app is not already running) and start
# the Julia program.
# 20071007 removed: open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
osascript 2>&1>/dev/null <<EOF
  tell application "System Events" to set ProcessList to get name of every process
  tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    if (ProcessList contains "Terminal") or ((count of every window) is less than 1) then
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "n" using command down
    end if
    do script ("exec bash -c \"PATH=${ROOT}/julia/bin:${PATH} OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 FONTCONFIG_PATH=${ROOT}/julia/etc/fonts GIT_EXEC_PATH=${ROOT}/julia/libexec/git-core GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=${ROOT}/julia/share/git-core exec '${ROOT}/julia/bin/julia'\"") in front window
  end tell
EOF

# Quit the Julia.application immediately after startup (ie. quitting
# it in the taskbar) because once it is started it cannot be restarted
# a second time. If Julia.app stays (eg. because of a crash) opened
# then restarting is not possible.
osascript 2>&1>/dev/null <<EOF
  tell application "julia"
    quit
  end tell
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't need a Terminal window to execute command line stuff. You would only use the Terminal if there was information you need to manually type in by hand. So you can probably just run the command using "do shell script" instead of "do script" in a Terminal window. Note that doing it this way won't use your bash profile file. So try this command all by itself in the applescript...

```
do shell script ("exec bash -c \"PATH=${ROOT}/julia/bin:${PATH} OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 FONTCONFIG_PATH=${ROOT}/julia/etc/fonts GIT_EXEC_PATH=${ROOT}/julia/libexec/git-core GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=${ROOT}/julia/share/git-core exec '${ROOT}/julia/bin/julia'\"")
```

Then you can add your other applescript commands as needed, just don't use the Terminal and thus your bash profile won't be used.

Comment: My command line program is interactive.  In fact, it's a REPL, so running it without a Terminal window won't work.